# Return type `this` is spoiled when argument is generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Here is the code: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKC2AXAFtA3gKGt6AHArgEYgCWw0EApiAGYAUAlAFzQokyY5fQBOli+HgDtWydlhwBfDBOwFiZaGAAmyxulnc+A4aPZKYbGADJ00GviHBGLBCmjSu06RgtXEJAPYj6AD1tIyAwaXMDeEIjQAJ7QALzQvgB0KmrBOAD06XCB0KZo5pbWzNkoANwOmlGJbkXcddiZ0ADyANaaYUIR0ABecdGJVLTqDVl2qHkFVjYlyOWOON3VhcP1XI2tGC41Ht7QAOYAPLDQlL6IlELKMGMAfHT+cMGcOB1dMfFJKSvQjccTNdMxnNKkspmlVhkshtQuFIr14lVBvRwb9NIsAeCIT8sgBRHg8Tw8FgABQJuEoPEQMQA5DVqdBlJ5KDAhJ5Iqd2JFdlTydBqbBqYlNkA)

```
class Smth {
    public self(): this {
        return this
    }

    public add() {
        return this as this & { func(): Smth }
    }
}

function f(x: Smth) {
    const y = x.add()    // Smth & { func(): Smth; }
    y.func()             // Ok
    const z = y.self()   // Smth & { func(): Smth; }
    z.func()             // Ok
}

function g<S extends Smth>(x: S) {
    const y = x.add()    // S & { func(): Smth; }
    y.func()             // Ok
    const z = y.self()   // S
    z.func()             // Error: Property 'func' does not exist on type 'S'.
}
```

Functions `f` and `g` have the only difference that the second one is generic:

```
function f(x: Smth) {
function g<S extends Smth>(x: S) {
```

But by some reason they start to behave differently on the line

```
const z = y.self()
```

Method `self` is declared as returning `this` and it works fine in non-generic function (`z` becomes `Smth & { func(): Smth; }`). But in generic function by some reason `z` gets just `S` instead of `S & { func(): Smth; }`.

**What should I write to get a correct type `S & { func(): Smth; }` after call `y.self()` in the generic function?**

Comment: @JackWilsdon, nope, `this` means the same type as `this` has, but doesn't guarantee the same instance. Anyway, I've shown 2 functions and in the first one it works as expected (at least by me). Are there any reasons, because of which these functions should have different expectations on what `this` return means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but not with polymorphic `this`. It works if you make `self` generic and have `this` inferred at call site.

```
class Smth {
    public self(): this {
    //public self<T>(this:T): T {
        return this
    }

    public add() {
        return this as this & { func(): Smth }
    }
}

function f(x: Smth) {
    const y = x.add()    // Smth & { func(): Smth; }
    y.func()             // Ok
    const z = y.self()   // Smth & { func(): Smth; }
    z.func()             // Ok
}

function g<S extends Smth>(x: S) {
    const y = x.add()    // S & { func(): Smth; }
    y.func()             // Ok
    const z = y.self()   // S
    z.func()             // Error: Property 'func' does not exist on type 'S'.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKC2AXAFtA3gKGt6AHArgEYgCWw0EApiAGYAUAlAFzQokyY7QD03BxZCtRoAeACoA+OmwhMxzaGPRYuOAE6VE+NQDtWydiuwBfDEbxFS5MABMbjZavWbtemdEj720AGTpoNPg6wIwsCCjQplymphiBwYgkAPZ69AAeYUjIDI44wCkQiNAAntAAvNBpAHS29jk4vHBZvv7xIQrhyADckebFVW0OTk6NAPIA1ub5OoXQAF7lJVVUtEM83E0RfmgBQe2ZKD1ROHMDe2vDDRsTGLFtiSnQAOYisNCUaYiUOjYwnVIZOA5Th5ApFUoVaq1C6NN7bXbBUKbbq9Lj9Qb1S5XaA3LjTWYLCr9Fb0TGw8ynDFYriNACiajUSTULAACozcJQ1IhSgByNo86A2JKUGA6JJFD7sIqPbkc6A82A8qq3IA)

Not sure why polymorphic `this` doesn't work in this case. I believe it should you might want to file an issue on GitHub.